# It's possible to associate Groovy file to Vaadin Designer?

Tags: groovy, eclipse-plugin, vaadin

I'm testing the wysiwyg designer of the Vaadin plugin. I tried to associate the `.groovy` extension to the `Vaadin Editor` (General > Editors > File Associations), but when I open the file I get:

> Could not open design view:
>
> Failed to find or parse visually editable class
>
> caused by NullPointerException

It's possible to associate groovy files to this editor? Am I missing some step?

Comment: I tried with GGTS and it complains about installing [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULRunner_1.9_Release_Notes). Even after installing it I get the same error you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visual editor supports only parsing and generating Java files.